# Trying to find an old book about people that live in trees

Tags: story-identification

A while back I read a book about these not humans but they live in trees. There is a disease that is the problem. At the end, it gets released into the ocean that is at the center of the world and the trees grow out of it. The characters spend a long time there.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SF&F Stack Exchange. In order to help others id the book, you may want to add more details. How long ago did you read it. Any idea on when it was published? Stuff like that. You can also take the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through the [help center section](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions.

Comment: Are there two sets of trees? Old ones they used to live in and new ones that get grown at the end of the book? Or something else.

Comment: Trees. Are these regular trees, or giant miles-tall trees? Is the disease a danger to the non-human people, or a danger to the trees? Are all the characters non-humans, or are there humans who arrive as well? Is it science fiction or fantasy? I've read a few books about people living in giant trees, so if you can nail down a few more details I might have a suggestion or two.

Comment: These Trees were giant mile-high ones, that would be affected by this disease. It was made by some person introduced at the end of the book trying to keep this very delicate plant from dying. It would only really affect the trees but since all of the characters lived in said trees that were a problem. From my recollection, they all were non-human and it is definitely a fantasy book.

Comment: Sorry Andrés, that doesn't match any of the giant-tree books I know. (I read mostly science fiction and very little fantasy.) The only giant tree book with a disease that I know of is Earth in Twilight by Doris Piserchia, and it's definitely science fiction, and the disease is a sentient creature (yeah, a living thinking pestilence) that affects people, not the trees.

Comment: I found the Green Sky trilogy by Zilpha Keatley Snyder. It's about people (fairies of a sort) who live in giant trees. I can't find evidence of a disease per se, but there is something called the tool-of-violence that is thrown into the Bottomless Lake at the end of the third book. It's a stretch to make it match the details you remember, so it's probably not your book.

Do you remember when you read this book? In the last five years? Ten years ago? Was it new then, or old? (I know that's hard to tell sometimes, because old books can be republished.)

Answer (score 1):

Midworld by Alan Dean Foster ?

From Wikipedia:
Midworld is a planet entirely covered by a rain forest three-quarters of a kilometer (almost half a mile) tall. Born is a member of the primitive human society that has lived peacefully on Midworld for hundreds of years, careful not to disturb the natural balance of the jungle.

(Can't see anything about a disease, and I never got round to reading the copy I've had for over 30 years)

Comment: No, there's no disease in Midworld, or the sequel Mid-Flinx.